# ctags with procedure pointers in Fortran

Tags: vim, fortran, ctags

Similarly to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497538/ctags-and-fortrans-interfaces) question, I would like to know if there is a way to have ctags recognized a procedure pointer, and of course where it points to.

Example:

```
if(code_is_2D) then
    get_convective => get_convective_2D
else
    get_convective => get_convective_3D
end if
```

By pressing `CTRL-]` on `get_convective`, I would like to be taken to whichever procedure it points to. I tried adding `--fortran-kinds=+i`, but that did not work.

**Edit:**

I didn't know there was multiple versions of ctags (exhuberant/universal) before LucHermitte's comment. I was using the former. I removed it and installed `universal-ctags`. Now, when using the flags `--fortran-kinds=+i`, I am being moved to the definition of the procedure pointer and NOT the actual procedure it points to.

Comment: Are you using the abandoned exhuberant-ctags or its maintained fork, i.e.universal-ctags?

Comment: @LucHermitte Please see edit

Comment: @solalito, in your own example `code_is_2D` could be read from input at run time, so how could Vim/ctags/you/me know what is the procedure pointed to if you're still coding?

Answer (score 2):

The only fields in your `tags` file that matter to Vim when you do `<C-]>` are:

- the tag,
- the filename,
- the Ex command used to find the tag.

The other fields are not used at all.

When you do `<C-]>`, Vim searches for the word under your cursor at the beginning of every line in your `tags` file. Something like:

```
/^\<get_convective\>
```

Then, it opens the associated filename and executes the associated Ex command. Something like:

```
:e path/to/filename
:/^\ \ \ \ get_convective
```

But you don't want the `get_convective` tag itself, you want whatever it points to *in your code*. The problem, here, is that Vim:

- doesn't understand your code,
- won't ever look at what points to what in the context of tag search.

Additionally, ctags itself:

- doesn't understand your code either,
- doesn't record that relationship anyway.

Therefore, you will almost certainly need a custom function like this one:

```
function! JumpToTagOrInterface()
    let this_line = getline('.')
    if this_line =~ '=>' && col('.') < stridx(this_line, '=>')
        execute 'tag' matchstr(this_line, '\S\{-}$')
    else
        tag <cword>
    endif
endfunction
nnoremap <key> :call JumpToTagOrInterface()<CR>
```

Note that this function assumes that your interfaces are indexed by ctags.

Answer (score 2):

No program (`ctags`, nor all possible variants) should be able to do something like this, simply because the conditional in your example is presumably evaluated at run time (e.g. because `code_is_2D` is read from/based on input), so there's no pointed-to procedure before running the program (indeed it's good practice to initialize pointers, included procedure pointers, to `NULL()`).

Maybe there's some trivial case (I can't think about one, but sure it's not the one in the question) where the pointed-to procedure is known at coding time, but I doubt about the usefulness of pointer procedures in that case.

Comment: One possible case is when conditional compiling is used. However, I don't think this holds true for the given case.